# Getting Selected Cell Index of a Gridview with unknown header and control name in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic-controls, dynamic-columns

I would like to get the text inputted on the textbox inside the gridview.
Thru selectedIndexChange I can get the selected row but currentIndex is not supported in ASP.net
I know you can get the selected cell thru header name or control name but this is not applicable on my scenario because the data including the header I bind on my gridview is dynamic. The first column is also dynamic that's why I programmatically created the textbox as columns meaning all of the controls have the same name.

[image: dynamic gridview]

my code to get the first column

```
   protected void dgvTask_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int columnindex = dgvTask.SelectedIndex;
        string task = dgvTask.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;          
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + task + "')", true);
        bindDgvTask();
    }
```

Comment: Use `TemplateFields` and add  `TextBox` controls, then you can register their `TextChanged` event and set `AutoPostBack` to true.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but unfortunately I cannot create TemplateFields because the header are dynamic.

Comment: you can change the `HeaderText` programmatically if that's what you want.